# Paperclip: how to save generated thumnails to amazon s3

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to upload a video to Amazon S3. The server is on heroku. 
I wrote a custom processor. In my custom processor, I execute a python script which generates 5 thumbnails for the video.

For now, the video is uploaded and the thumbnails generated. However, the thumbnails are on heroku. My question is how can I generate the thumbnails and save them on Amazon S3?

```
    # lib/paperclip_processors/custom.rb
    module Paperclip
      class Custom < Processor
        def make

          basename = File.basename(file.path, File.extname(file.path))
          dst_format = options[:format] ? ".\#{options[:format]}" : ''

          dst = Tempfile.new([basename, dst_format])
          dst.binmode

          #generate thumbnails using run.py 
          `python run.py #{file.path}`


          dst
        end
      end
end
```

Comment: Have you verified that s3 is properly configured, i.e. setup with paperclip default processor and verify that images are being put to s3 as expected?